# Puterman or Sutton Barto?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I wonder which of these two books is better to read for a beginner in RL and which are the pros and cons of them.

Also, if you know any book that in your opinion is better for a beginner in RL, feel free to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Sutton and Barto (2nd edition is out!). Also David's Silver slides for the RL course at UCL plus the youtube videos from his classes. You can start with the lecture videos and the slides and going back to the book for more details and exercises. Putterman is quite hard for a beginner, heavy on math and focusing on Dynamic Programming mostly.

Comment: Just my personal opinion: The book is good but the lectures by David Silver are not worth spending your time. Sergey Levine is much clearer in his explanations.

Comment: @MachineLearner does Sergey Levine have a collection of lecture videos anywhere?

Comment: @mLstudent33 The non-listed youtube playlist can be found via Sergey Levine's university page. Here is the direct link to the playlist https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLkFD6_40KJIxJMR-j5A1mkxK26gh_qg37.

Answer (score 0):

Manning Publications has a new (late 2018) [Video Course](https://www.manning.com/livevideo/reinforcement-learning-in-motion) out , where the Author, Phil Tabor, builds RL apps (e.g. a robot in a maze) using Python.

Readers/Participants are encouraged to follow along, implementing a few new functions at the end of each section. (I for one try to do these exercises, but usually do not get working code, just a sketch with pseudocode).

Code samples are here on Github: [Reinforcement Learning In Motion](https://github.com/philtabor/Reinforcement-Learning-In-Motion)